# JButtons Overlap Components When Hovered On

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have set up a JPanel which is on top (Z-Axis) of a JButton. While hovering over this JPanel, if a JButton is also hovered on, the JButton automatically gets repainted on top of all components. This is not desirable for my program to work properly. Any ideas as to why this is happening and how I can fix this issue? Thanks for any help offered!

This is a quick and simple replica of my code:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
contentPane = new JPanel();
contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
setContentPane(contentPane);
contentPane.setLayout(null);

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 102));
panel.setBounds(0, 0, 169, 261);
contentPane.add(panel);
panel.setVisible(false);

JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        panel.setVisible(!panel.isVisible());
    }
});
btnNewButton.setBounds(68, 70, 130, 70);
contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
```

The JPanel begins on top (Z-Axis) until the JButton is hovered on (even if the JButton is covered by the JPanel). I hope this is enough information for your requirements.

Comment: You're overriding a paint method without calling it's super method.  You're using alpha based color for the background color of a opaque component ... as a couple of guesses.  For something more concrete, consider providing a [mcve]

Comment: *"I have set up a JPanel which is on top of a JButton"* - Why?

Comment: It is used as a simple side menu in my program, I hope the edit will make the question more understandable.

Comment: (1-) `I hope the edit will make the question more understandable` - not to me. First you say the panel is on the "top". I have no idea if you mean top as in the "north" part of the frame or "on top" like a popup menu that is displayed on the Z-axis, instead of the x/y axis. Now you say it is a "side" panel. Also all the relevant information should be included with the question so all the information is in one place. And you still haven't posted our [mcve] so we still have no ideas what custom code you are using to cause the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swing UIs, almost always use layout managers. See this to learn how to use layout managers:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html

So, in your code remove these lines:

```
contentPane.setLayout(null);
panel.setBounds(0, 0, 169, 261);
btnNewButton.setBounds(68, 70, 130, 70);
```

And do something like:

```
contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
contentPane.add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! My issue has been resolved by this fix, wish you all the best.